# the deviceToken is not register in parse push notification in my app?

Tags: ios, parsing, notifications, push

I have an application in app store and I use parse push notification in this app ,
but the app don't ask to register ,and the deviceToken not token .

I make every  thing like what is written in this tutorial 
https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

can any one help me ?

Comment: are you trying on the simulator?

Comment: @Aeon Aldar push notification delegate method will not called on simulator

Comment: my app is now in app store .

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by make new iOS Provisioning Profiles which enable push notification .